# How to change bar color for recurring tasks in MS Project 2013?

Tags: microsoft-project-2013

MS Project 2013.

I am trying to change recurring task **summary** Gantt chart bar color. I can change individual task's bar color using flags. But this method does not work for summary tasks...

Anybody can figure this one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right here is a solution:
1. In Gantt Chart area click right button and choose "Bar Styles".
2. In the new window choose "*Rolled Up Tasks" row.
3. In "Bars" tab change the colors u want.
4. Click OK and that's it!